# I need to make an annotation that by placing it on the dto class will create a crud controller

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am writing a program in which I am supposed to write a personalized annotation that, by placing that annotation on the model, creates a controller for that model from the generic controller that I have written.

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller/")
public class GenericMVCController {
    final Map<String, String> annotAttributeMap;
    private Service service;

    public GenericMVCController(Map<String, String> annotAttributeMap,Service service) {
        this.service=service;
        this.annotAttributeMap = annotAttributeMap;

    }

    @GetMapping(value = "view/page/{page}/size/{size}")
    public ModelAndView getView(@PathVariable(name = "page") int page, @PathVariable(name = "size") int size, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for read

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "update/form/id/{id}")
    public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for open update form

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "update/commit")
    public ModelAndView updateCommit(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "formData") DTO formData, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for update commit

        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/group/view/page/0/size/10");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "delete")
    public ModelAndView delete(@RequestParam(name = "itemsSelected") String itemsSelected, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for delete

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CRUDForm {
    String url() ;
    String createURL() default "";
    String readURL() default "";
    String updateURL() default "";

    String deleteURL() default "";
    String[] exceptTheFields() default {};
}
```

```
public class CustomAnnotationScanning {
    public CustomAnnotationScanning(){
        CRUDFormScanner();
    }

    public void CRUDFormScanner(){

        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider=new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(CRUDForm.class));

        Set<BeanDefinition> beanDefs = provider
                .findCandidateComponents("com.dwteam.avaservis");

        List<String> annotatedBeans = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BeanDefinition bd : beanDefs) {
            if (bd instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition) {
                Map<String, Object> annotAttributeMap = ((AnnotatedBeanDefinition) bd)
                        .getMetadata()
                        .getAnnotationAttributes(CRUDForm.class.getCanonicalName());

                    // I need create controller for any bd



            }
        }

    }

}
```

I tried this code and expected it to take the map values ​​from the map and put them in the annotation, but it could not recognize the map.

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = annotAttributeMap.get("url"))
public class GenericMVCController {
    final Map<String, String> annotAttributeMap;
    private Service service;

    public GenericMVCController(Map<String, String> annotAttributeMap,Service service) {
        this.service=service;
        this.annotAttributeMap = annotAttributeMap;

    }

    @GetMapping(value = annotAttributeMap.get("read"))
    public ModelAndView getView(@PathVariable(name = "page") int page, @PathVariable(name = "size") int size, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for read

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = annotAttributeMap.get("update"))
    public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for open update form

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = annotAttributeMap.get("updateCommit"))
    public ModelAndView updateCommit(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "formData") DTO formData, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for update commit

        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/group/view/page/0/size/10");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = annotAttributeMap.get("delete"))
    public ModelAndView delete(@RequestParam(name = "itemsSelected") String itemsSelected, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        // logic for delete

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Annotation values have to be compile-time constants. You can't use just any expression there.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello, dear @Jorn. Do you have any idea with which I can write a generic controller for my program.